# Fetch list item attachment by name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, list-item, attachments

I am trying to write custom code for list item attachments. As it is not allowed to overwrite them, I will check if file already exists. If yes, will delete and then upload again.

I found a method [SP.AttachmentCollection.getByFileName Method (sp.js)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245502.aspx) which can fetch list item by file name. Does anyone has sample code for this?

I am not able to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply invoke a REST call to following URL

`/_api/lists/getByTitle('ListTitle')/getItemById(1)/AttachmentFiles/getByFileName('filename')`

Then check the response to see if file exists or not.

**JSOM**

```
function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    var item = listItem;
    var total = item.get_attachmentFiles().get_count();
    if (total > 0) {
        console.log(total + " file attachments");

        //Attachment exists and no need to re attach
    }       
}

function onFailure(sender, args) {
    //failed
}

var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ListTitle");
var listItem = list.getItemById(1);
clientContext.load(listItem);
clientContext.load(listItem.get_attachmentFiles().getByFileName("FileName"));
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, onFailure));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am looking for JSOM code.

Comment: Ok. But you can still invoke a REST call from JSOM which will be easier. I will look around and see any JSOM sample is available.

Comment: @Garima I have added JSOM sample.

Comment: Thanks Amal. really helpful. I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: Once you've gotten the attachment, how can you use that to retrieve its binary? It looks like this simply shows binary info. If I perform a regular "GET" on the filepath itself, this doesn't seem to return the binary properly for most file types..